# Hibernate @ColumnTransformer( read = "...", write="...") gives some errors, how can I solve it?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations, aes

I was trying to use AES with hibernate columnTransformer annotation but gives me some errors.

---

- The database was generated with Hibernate.
- Only appears when I try to use AES on read and write parameters on @org.hibernate.annotations.ColumnTransformer.

---

> My Employeeclass

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;

@Entity()
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVesionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private Integer employeeId;

    @org.hibernate.annotations.NaturalId
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "password")
    @org.hibernate.annotations.ColumnTransformer(
        read = "decrypt( 'AES', '00', password)",
        write = "encrypt('AES', '00', ?)"
    )
    private String password;

    private int accessLevel;

    public Employee(Integer employeeId, String userName, String password, int accessLevel) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.password = password;
        this.accessLevel = accessLevel;
    }

    //Getters and Setters

}
```

> My Main class

```
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import hibernate.examples.columntransformers.readandwriteexpressions.Employee;

public class App {

    private static EntityManagerFactory emf;
    private static EntityManager em;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("LAVM");
        em = emf.createEntityManager();

        try {

            em.getTransaction().begin();            

            Employee emp = new Employee(123, "someUserName", "somePassword", 1);

            em.persist(emp);
            em.getTransaction().commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {                
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            em.close();
            emf.close();
        }
    }
}
```

> Gives me these errors

```
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:94)
at hibernate.examples.main.App.main(App.java:38)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1763)
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1677)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:82)
... 1 more


Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:190)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:62)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3124)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3587)
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:103)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:453)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:345)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1218)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:421)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77)
... 1 more


Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'encrypt'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:187)
... 14 more


oct 13, 2016 11:08:31 AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH000030: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an exception related to **Incorrect parameter count** in the call to native function `encrypt`.

Check the number of parameters for `decrypt` and `encrypt` functions, I guess it should be **two** and not three as you used for password column.

Answer (score 0):

you have used :

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.ColumnTransformer(
        read = "decrypt( 'AES', '00', password)",
        write = "encrypt('AES', '00', ?)"
    )
```

where decrypt and encrypt are the db functions. Please check if these functions exist and have the same method signature as you used in the entity class.